# Masking non-vegetation areas in image

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, masking, vegetation-index, filtering

I'm having a little trouble masking non-vegetation areas in my images.

I'm using Sentinel-2 images, and I have land use and cover across my country (Brazil). To this end, I reclassified this land use and cover image into (1 - forest and natural vegetation areas) and (0 - for other uses). With this I'm trying to mask everything that is not vegetation, that is, I don't want anything to be visualized (0). However, I can't get a result with the script I've been adapting.

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
 var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
      return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

  

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                .filterBounds(table3)
                 .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-08-31')
                 .select(['B8','B4', 'B3', 'B2','QA60'])
                                    // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                 .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);



//there's i make function which convert imagecollection to one image with bands
var mergeBands = function(image, previous) {
  return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image, ['B8', 'B4', 'B3','B2']);
};

var merged = ee.Image(dataset.iterate(mergeBands, ee.Image([])));
print('merged', merged);

var MAPBIOMAS20 = image
//var MAPBIOMAS20_filtrada = image.remap([3,4,12],[3,4,12])
// não pode usar o .map para apenas uma imagem
//var reclassified = function(image) {
//  return image.remap([3,4,12],[3,4,12], 'vegetation');
//};
//var new_ds = MAPBIOMAS20.map(reclassified)
//print(new_ds);

// Remap values.
var MAPBIOMAS20reclass = ee.Image(1)
         .where(MAPBIOMAS20.gt(0).and(MAPBIOMAS20.lte(5)), 1)
         .where(MAPBIOMAS20.gt(10).and(MAPBIOMAS20.lte(12)), 1)
         .where(MAPBIOMAS20.gt(6).and(MAPBIOMAS20.lte(9)), 0)
         .where(MAPBIOMAS20.gt(12).and(MAPBIOMAS20.lte(50)), 0)


//Map.addLayer(MAPBIOMAS20reclass, {min:0, max:1}, 'MAP20RCLASS', true)
//Map.addLayer(MAPBIOMAS20reclass, {min:0, max:12}, 'MAP20RCLASS', true)
var CERRADO_VEG = MAPBIOMAS20reclass.clip(table);
Map.addLayer(CERRADO_VEG, {min:0, max:1}, 'MAP20RCLASS_cerrado', true)

////print(cerrado1)
//var CERRADO_VEG = MAPBIOMAS20reclass.clip(table);

// Create a Boolean land mask from the SWIR1 band; water is value 0, land is 1.
var landMask = CERRADO_VEG.select('constant').gt(0);
print('Land mask', landMask);
Map.addLayer(landMask, {palette: ['yellow', 'green']}, 'Land mask');

var trueColorViz = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 2700,
  gamma: 1.3
};

// Apply the single-band land mask to all image bands; pixel values equal to 0
// in the mask become invalid in the image.
var imgMasked = merged.updateMask(landMask);
print('Image, land only', imgMasked);
Map.addLayer(imgMasked, trueColorViz, 'Image, land only');
```

After that I still intend to obtain vegetation indices for my area, but I already want to exclude what is not vegetation.

Can someone help me?